# Go Templates: Can't identify field <field> in type string (struct being passed to template treated as string?)

Tags: go, go-templates

I have the following code for an image modal pop-out. `Photos` is a struct that's passed to the frontend from the server. An instance of `Photos` is passed to the following template:

```html
...
{{ $info := .GenInfo true }}
<img src={{ $info.Url }} data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#{{ $info.Id }}" />
{{ template "photo-modal" $info }}
{{ end }}
{{ $info = .GenInfo false }}
<img src={{ $info.Url }} data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#{{ $info.Id }}" />
{{ template "photo-modal" $info }}
{{ end }}
...
```

Because Go only allows a single attribute to be passed to a template, I created the following function to pass the url and a generated id to the sub-template:

```golang
type Photos struct {
  LeftUrl  string
  RightUrl string
  Date     string
}

type photoInfo struct {
  Id  string
  Url string
}

func (p *Photo) GenInfo(isLeft bool) photoInfo {
  var info photoInfo
  if isLeft {
    info.Url = p.LeftPhoto
  } else {
    info.Url = p.RightPhoto
  }
  
  reg, _ := regexp.Compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")
  info.Id = reg.ReplaceAllString(info.Url, "")

  return info
}
```

Here is the modal template that I'm trying to make reusable elsewhere in the app:

```html
{{ define "photo-modal" }}
<div class="modal fade" id={{ .Id }} tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src={{ .Url }} />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{ end }}
```

The app compiles, but when I try and load the page, I get the following error:

```sh
template: photo-modal.html:2:30: executing "photo-modal$htmltemplate_stateHTMLCmt" at <.Id>: can't evaluate field Id in type string
```

and the page itself crashes.

I would appreciate any help on this, I'm not sure why. Maybe the struct is being treated as a string for some reason? If that's what's happening, how can I get the template to treat the struct as a struct?

Comment: *"Maybe the struct is being treated as a string for some reason?"* -- No. If the template error claims that `.` is `string` then that means that a `string` was passed to it. But AFAICT there is not enough code here to determine where you are making the mistake. Consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: And just to confirm the above, [here](https://go.dev/play/p/2zKrJRJME9l) you can see that the code you've provided works (with small adjustments to the receiver type and field names which I assume are a typo in the question).